# Vertical lines when exporting jpeg file in libjpeg c++

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life, libjpeg

I don't understand why when i export to jpeg i get vertical lines every 1080 pixels. what am i doing wrong?

full repo -> https://github.com/ElPettego/swg_bg

vertical lines example -> https://github.com/ElPettego/swg_bg/blob/master/swg_test.jpg

```
void export_jpg(std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid) {
    struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;

    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);    

    FILE* outfile = fopen("swg_test.jpg", "wb");
    if (!outfile) {
        exit(1);
    }
    
    jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, outfile);

    cinfo.image_width = width;
    cinfo.image_height = height;
    cinfo.input_components = 3;
    cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;

    jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
    jpeg_set_quality(&cinfo, 100, TRUE);

    jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);

    while (cinfo.next_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {
        JSAMPROW row_buffer = new JSAMPLE[cinfo.image_width * 3];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            row_buffer[x * 3] = 0;
            row_buffer[x * 3 + 2] = 0;
            row_buffer[x * 3 + 1] =  grid[cinfo.next_scanline][x] ? 255 : 0;

        }
        jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, &row_buffer, 1);
        delete[] row_buffer;
    }
    jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
    fclose(outfile);
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);
}
```

i tried modifying the bounds of the for loops in new_generation function and quality of export but the error still remains(https://github.com/ElPettego/swg_bg/blob/master/main.c%2B%2B)

Comment: Is it possible that your input data has the vertical lines?

Comment: Off topic, but you should pass `vector` by reference, not by value:  `void export_jpg(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid)`.

Comment: i dont think so i generate randomically at the start. even if there is a problem with random generation, in the new generations the lines should vanish. i think it is a problem with libjpeg but i cant figure out what it is. @MarkRansom

Comment: ok thank u, i will modify it @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: The other thing is that usage of `std::vector` instead of `new[]` would make the `while` loop run a lot more efficient.  A declaration of `std::vector<JSAMPLE>` outside the loop, and then using `vector.clear();` would eliminate the need to call `new[]` and `delete[]` constantly in the loop.  If there are hundreds or maybe thousands of scan lines, this would greatly speed things up.

Comment: Just as a test, add a second loop: `for (x=0;x<width;x+=1080);row_buffer[x*3]=255;` and see how it changes things. If your line turns yellow, it's a problem with your data; if nothing changes it's a problem with libjpeg or your usage of it.

Comment: As an aside, libjpeg is one of the most widely used libraries out there.  Highly doubtful it would have a bug.

Comment: My test won't work, because your description missed one important detail: the lines aren't 1080 apart, they're 1084 apart, starting at 1082.  So use `for(x=1082;x+=1084;x<width)`.

Comment: `vector<vector>` is not a very efficient solution if all internal vectors have same size. try `vector<int> grid{h*w}` instead. Also replace `rawbuffer` with `vector<JSAMPLE> buff{3*w};` you can access the underlying array through `data(buff)` as a pointer to first element. By putting the buffer outside the loops, you can prevent unnecessary alloc/deallocs inside the loops and increase performance.

Comment: You seem to have fixed the vertical lines but I have to point out that RGB JPEG isn't a good choice for saving 1 bit per pixel images. Staying with JPEG you would be better off with just a luminance channel and encoding JCS_GREYSCALE - that should get you a filesize ~880k as greyscale JPEG. BTW the chroma channels in your image are not zero so it is way bigger than it should be at 3MB. Split to RGB channels to see this. Clearly visible on the traffic lights. Saving as 256 colour indexed BMP is ~2MB and as a 2 colour indexed BMP about ~250k. Not sure which modern programs can read them...

Answer (score 3):

Simple undefined behavior.

But you'd never know it by looking at the code in the question here, you need to look at the code in the repo that wasn't included.

Look at how `grid` is created:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid(width, std::vector<int>(height, 1));
```

Notice that `width` is defining the size of the *outer* vector, while `height` is defining the size of each *inner* vector.

Now look at how you're accessing the grid:

```
    row_buffer[x * 3 + 1] =  grid[cinfo.next_scanline][x] ? 255 : 0;
```

The first pair of brackets dereferences the outer vector, while the second dereferences the inner vector.  This is backwards to the way the vector was defined.  Since width is greater than height, you're accessing out-of-bounds elements of the vector.

P.S. there's other out-of-bounds accesses lurking in that code, you should give it a once-over.